# How can I retrieve success/failure messages after executing a statement?

Tags: oracle, odp.net

How can I fetch the messages displayed by Oracle after running a query? For example, if I write

```
create table t;
```

it displays this message

```
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

However if I write

```
create table t(id int);
```

it displays

```
table created.
```

I want to fetch these messages like

```
 ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

or

```
 Table Created
```

The problem statement is: 
I want user to enter his query in a text area in web browser. I will fetch and pass on that query to Oracle and want to display the same message that would have been displayed to him had he been writing those queries on SQL*Plus instead of in the browser.

In simple words, I want to create a page that kind of simulates SQL*Plus.

I am using ASP.NET 4.5 in C# with ODP.NET and Oracle 10g. From my research, I have somehow come to know that in case of successful execution, Oracle return some SQLCA code that is manipulated and displayed into a proper message by SQL*Plus.

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: `SQL*Plus error logging` is now easy with release 11.1 and above. See my answer.

Comment: For the ORA-xxxx message retrieval, are you just talking about the Message from an [OracleException](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleExceptionClass.htm)? You'd need to make up your own 'success' messages though, based on lack of an exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `SQL*Plus`, then you can trap the error messages into `sperrorlog` table. This new feature was introduced in `release 11.1`. You can log the error into this table for the following types of errors -

- ORA Errors
- SP2 Errors
- PLS Errors

I have written a small article on it, you can have a look at it for more information. [SQL*Plus error logging – New feature release 11.1](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/sqlplus-error-logging-new-feature-release-11-1/).

All you need to do is `set errorlogging on` for your session.

This is how the `sperrorlog` table looks like when described -

```
SQL> desc sperrorlog;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 USERNAME                                           VARCHAR2(256)
 TIMESTAMP                                          TIMESTAMP(6)
 SCRIPT                                             VARCHAR2(1024)
 IDENTIFIER                                         VARCHAR2(256)
 MESSAGE                                            CLOB
 STATEMENT                                          CLOB
```

Let's see an example -

```
SQL> set errorlogging on;
SQL> selct * from dual;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "selct * fr..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> select timestamp, username, script, statement, message from sperrorlog;

TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SCRIPT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

STATEMENT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

11-SEP-13 01.27.29.000000 AM
SCOTT


TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SCRIPT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

STATEMENT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

selct * from dual;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "selct * fr..." - rest of line ignored.
```

There is an issue when `rollback` is used with this feature. I have an article for the workaround, [SQL*Plus error logging – workaround for ROLLBACK issue](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/sqlplus-error-logging-workaround-for-rollback-issue/)

Comment: thanks for replying.But i also asked if there is no error then how to get the message returned by oracle like in successful creation of table, altering of table, creation of proc,function or insertion,deletion,updation. In all these cases, if it succesful, then oracle displays appropriate messages. how to fetch that message.

Comment: @Mohit - 'Oracle' doesn't return those messages, the client (e.g. SQL*Plus) generates them based on the lack of an error and/or the affected rowcount. Exactly how depends on the client; SQL*Plus uses OCI methods I believe. You can generate your own versions if you need to using the same logic.

Comment: @AlexPoole -Thanks for guiding.Can you tell me how to replicate that OCI methods logic if I need to as I want them to be a replica of Sql Plus messages.

Comment: @AlexPoole- Well I am using ASP.NET with ODP.NET in C#. I am using a connected approach. I simply want to know whether there is any way of getting the message displayed in SQL Plus result pane programatically. You can see http://sqlfiddle.com/. On typing wrong  query there, they return exactly the same message which a sql plus would return.

Comment: @Mohit, when I answered to your question, I took only error messages into consideration, as I missed your other point. Anyway, as Alex mentioned, could you please reconcile all your pints and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try the "InfoMessage" event:

http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/OracleInfoMessageEventArgsClass.htm

```
// C#

using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;


class InfoMessageSample
{

  public static void WarningHandler(object src, OracleInfoMessageEventArgs args)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Source object is: " + src.GetType().Name);
      Console.WriteLine("InfoMessageArgs.Message is " + args.Message);
      Console.WriteLine("InfoMessageArgs.Source is " + args.Source);
  }
  static void Main()
  {
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("User Id=scott;" + 
      "Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle;");

    con.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    //Register to the InfoMessageHandler
    cmd.Connection.InfoMessage += new OracleInfoMessageEventHandler(WarningHandler);

    cmd.CommandText = 
      "create or replace procedure SelectWithNoInto( " +
      "  empname in VARCHAR2) AS " +
      "BEGIN " +
      "  select * from emp where ename = empname; " +
      "END SelectWithNoInto;";

    // Execute the statement that produces a warning
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Clean up
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Dispose();
  }
}
```